# Как написать программу, которая введет 10 чисел и найдет наибольшее число из введенных чисел, которое больше чем 0.5 и меньше 3? (на js)

Tags: javascript

Как написать программу, которая введет 10 чисел и найдет наибольшее число из введенных чисел, которое больше чем 0.5 и меньше 3? (на js)
Я так понял что нужно использовать math.max и math.random(могу быть не прав)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот так:

```js
function createNumbers(min, max, count) {
  const numbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    numbers[i] = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(1);
  }
  return numbers;
}

function maxNumber(arr) {
  let max = -Infinity;

  for (let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] > max && arr[i] > 0.5 && arr[i] < 3) max = arr[i];
  }

  return (max === -Infinity) ? NaN : max;
}

const numbers_array = createNumbers(0.1, 11, 10);

console.log(numbers_array);
console.log(`Max number: ${maxNumber(numbers_array)}`);
```